# Cannot Print names of all result links on first 5 pages of Google.com in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to print names of all result links on the first 5 pages on Google.com

Scenario is,
1) Go to www.google.com and search for something.
2) Print names of all result links on first 5 pages

I am able to print all the result links of first page and click next page link. But second page links are not printing. I think the reason may be with the xpath changing in second page. If so, how do I print all the links of 2nd 3rd 4th and 5th page.
Kindly help me in solving this solution.

```
package com;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Exercise2 {
static WebDriver d;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProfilesIni prop = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile seleniumProfile = prop.getProfile(("Selenium"));
         d = new FirefoxDriver();
        d.manage().window().maximize();
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        d.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        d.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        d.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //Print names of all result links on first page.
        String part1 = "//div[@id='rso']/div[2]/div[";
        String part2  = "]/div/h3/a";

        for(int i=2;i<=5;i++){
            String part3 = "//div[@id='navcnt']/table/tbody/tr/td[";
            String part4 = "]";
            int a = 1;

            while(isElementPresent(part1+a+part2)){
                String text = d.findElement(By.xpath(part1+a+part2)).getText();
                System.out.println(text);
                a++;
            }
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("*************Next Page**********");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            d.findElement(By.xpath(part3+i+part4)).click();
        }

}
    public static boolean isElementPresent(String xpathexp){
        List<WebElement> allList = d.findElements(By.xpath(xpathexp));
        //WebElement nextPages = d.findElement(By.xpath(nextPage1));
        if(allList.size()==0)
        {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Check Solution i have posted. Also it is my first program in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElements> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++)
{
   string firstLink = links[i].getAttribute("href");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code.

```
package javaselenium;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
/**
 *
 * @author Muhammad USman
 */
public class JavaSelenium {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Hello Wrold");
    GetUrls("Selenium");
}   

public static  ArrayList GetUrls(String keyWord)
{
    FirefoxDriver driver;        
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"); 
    WebElement qElement;
    qElement = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    qElement.sendKeys(keyWord);
    qElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaSelenium.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //give number how mange pages you want to crawl
    int nPageToCrawl=5;
    List links;
    links=new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < nPageToCrawl; i++) {            
        if(i>0)
        {
            System.out.println("***Click on Next Page***");
            //Click on Next Page
            driver.findElement(By.id("pnnext")).click();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaSelenium.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        //it will get all links of pageLinks
        List<WebElement>  pageLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".r>a"));
        for (WebElement pageLink : pageLinks) {
            links.add(pageLink.getAttribute("href"));
            System.out.println(pageLink.getText());
            System.out.println(pageLink.getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
    //close browser
    driver.quit();
    return (ArrayList) links;
}
```

}

if any issue then let me know.

Comment: I will try and let u all know :)